# grep PCRE still greedy

Tags: grep, regex

I'm searching a multi-line text file and want to match a string from a certain word until the first match of another word:

```
start
word1
word1
word1
word1
end
word2
word2
word2
start
word3
word3
word3
end
```

Here's what I use: `grep -Pzo "(?s)start.*?end" file.txt`

And it matches everything in the above text string from beginning to end, whereas I want to match only until the first `end` occurance, i.e.:

```
start
word1
word1
word1
word1
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Somehow the non-greedy `?` quantifier is not working as I expected it.

Thank you for your time and contributions!

Comment: I think perhaps it is matching non-greedily - but twice

Comment: Isn't that greedy? How could I limit it to only the first match?

Comment: Greedy would indeed be matching "everything in the above text string from beginning to end" but that's not what's happening, is it? When I test your expression, lines containing `word2` are missing - if you try `grep -Pzo -b '(?s)start.*?end' file.txt` you will see that it matches once at byte offset 0 and again at byte offset 52

Comment: So is it some loop that's forming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *greedy* match would include everything from the first `start` to the last `end`, thus:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)start.*end' file.txt
start                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
end                                                                                                                                                                                          
word2                                                                                                                                                                                        
word2                                                                                                                                                                                        
word2                                                                                                                                                                                        
start                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

What you are actually seeing is *two* separate non-greedy matches, output on separate "lines" per the `-o` option - except that with `-Z`, "lines" are actually denoted by the null character instead of the newline character:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)start.*?end' file.txt
start                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
endstart                                                                                                                                                                                     
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

Since we can't see the null byte here, it's clearer if you add `-b` to indicate the byte offsets of the two matches within the "line":

```
$ grep -Pzo -b '(?s)start.*?end' file.txt
0:start                                                                                                                                                                                      
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
word1                                                                                                                                                                                        
end52:start                                                                                                                                                                                  
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
word3                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

Since the `-o` outputs are null-separated, you could pipe the result through `head -z` to get just the first match:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)start.*?end' file.txt | head -z -n 1
start
word1
word1
word1
word1
end
```

Alternatively you could use perl itself

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say for /(start.*?end)/s' file.txt
```

which only prints one match in spite of the `for` loop since the `g` flag is omitted.